# Anrede für "divers"

Tags: gender, formality

In vielen **Kontaktformularen** muss eine Anrede ausgewählt werden. Klassischerweise sind als Antwortmöglichkeiten *Herr* und *Frau* vorgegeben. Immer häufiger gibt es auch eine dritte Option, meistens lautet sie: *Divers*. Ist dies die richtige und beste Variante?

Ich meine, dass idealerweise stattdessen das Anrede-Feld optional sein sollte, sodass der Wert leer bleiben kann. Wo das aus irgendwelchen technischen Gründen nicht möglich sein sollte, bspw. weil die Anrede unverändert in Serienbriefvorlagen (üblicherweise zusammen mit dem Nachnamen) verwendet wird, bedarf es aber einer Lösung. Eine Begrüßungsfloskel wie *Sehr geehrte(r) Divers Müller* wirkt aber sehr falsch. Wenn möglich, ziehe ich etwas wie *Hallo A. Müller* vor. Ich weiß aber, dass dies nicht immer und überall möglich ist.

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass dies eine Frage zur deutschen Sprache ist. Du schlägst ja bereits einen guten Ansatz vor.

Comment: Ich finde A. Müller unpersönlich, dann lieber Hallo Andreas Müller.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it can - if at all - only be answered in an opinion-based way (and a quite controversial one at that).

Comment: Dass die Auswahlmöglichkeit im Formular "Divers" heißt, muss ja auch nicht heißen, dass das dann auch wirklich so als Anrede benutzt wird. "Sehr geehrte(r) Divers Müller" ist natürlich absurd.

Comment: Geht es um eine Software oder Benutzeroberfläche, die Du unter Kontrolle hast und die nach Deinen Wünschen implementiert werden soll? Oder geht es um fremde Software? Es gibt keine allgemein anerkannte Regel, sondern sehr unterschiedliche Ansichten über dieses Thema.

Answer (score 1):

In der Praxis ist zum Zeitpunkt dieser Antwort (Ende 2022) eine verbreitete Handhabe, dass die Anrede frei gelassen wird.

Was die technischen Aspekte angeht:

- Idealerweise sollten Serienbriefvorlagen & Co. auch optionale Felder bereitstellen.
- Ein Notbehelf könnte ansonsten sein, einen leeren String (" ") / Leerzeichen zu verwenden.
- Falls das wiederum nicht möglich ist, könnte auch das "Gendersternchen" ("*") eingesetzt werden.

Comment: Für wessen Praxis gilt das und welche Belege gibt es dafür?

Comment: @userunknown Der beschriebene Umstand ist ein Teil zeitgenössischer Sprache. Zeitgenössische Sprache ist dynamisch und ihr Regelwerk ist deskriptiv, nicht normativ. Vielleicht hilft Ihnen das weiter. Ansonsten kann Ihre Frage so nicht beantwortet werden, weil der Bezug der Frage nicht klar ist.

Comment: Wir sind hier eigentlich per Du miteinander. Einem Mann der Sprachpraxis hätte das nicht verborgen bleiben sollen. Dafür, dass Sprache deskriptiv ist, kommen Deine Aussagen ziemlich normativ daher. Sprache ist nicht nur dynamisch, sondern auch heterogen, d.h. vielerorts ist der Stand ein anderer.

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt sehr viele Varianten, das umzusetzen - es gibt hier keinen Goldstandard oder eine Regel, die das vereinheitlichen würde.

Wie so immer, würde ich mich jedoch an den [Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/geschlechtsneutrale-anrede-gendern-e-mails) halten, bzw. was dort empfohlen wird (das vorher fragen streiche ich mal, da ich denke, dass das selten zielführend ist und im Kontext von Serienbriefen nicht sinnvoll ist):

> [...] Eine andere Möglichkeit wäre die Anrede mit Vor- und Nachnamen – man
> kann etwa problemlos ausweichen auf „Guten Tag, Silke Segler“. Und für
> eine allgemeine Anrede mehrerer, nicht definierter Personen sowohl in
> der Korrespondenz als auch bei öffentlichen Anlässen gibt es
> zahlreiche Mittel der neutralen und alle umfassenden Anrede. Von
> „Liebe Lehrkräfte“ bis „Sehr geehrte Anwesende“ ist vieles möglich.

Ich habe das damals im Studium in einer Software-Anwendung von mir sehr plump mit "Sehr geehrtes Individuum {Nachname}" umgesetzt. Ansonsten würde ich mit deinem Lösungsvorschlag mit dem Hallo {Vorname} {Nachname} eigentlich komplett mitgehen. Am Ende des Tages ist es glaube ich lediglich relevant, hier nicht das falsche Geschlecht zu verwenden, um eventuelle Konflikte aufgrunddessen zu vermeiden.

Answer (score 1):

Dass man heutzutage die Anrede besser weglässt und stattdessen Vor- und Nachname verwendet, wurde ja bereits gesagt. Wenn dies aus technischen Gründen nicht möglich ist, könnte man für die Geschlechtsangabe "divers" die Anrede "Frau/Herr" machen und für die Geschlechtsangabe "keine Angabe" die Anrede "Person".

> Sehr geehrte Person Müller

hört sich zwar auch nicht super an, aber besser als "Sehr geehrte(r) Divers Müller" ist es allemal.

> Sehr geehrte/r Frau/Herr Müller

scheint mir auch eine vernünftige Alternative.

Hintergrund ist der, dass sich mit "divers" meist Menschen bezeichnen, die sich als nicht-binär identifizieren oder intersex sind. Man findet sich also eher zwischen den Geschlechtern wieder, daher beides: Frau und Herr. Mit "divers" wird auch oft das "dritte Geschlecht" bezeichnet. [Offiziell](https://www.bundestag.de/resource/blob/586098/9e46a6af839411688142114c73efc6f9/beilage_divers_07_01_19-data.pdf) wird es folgendermaßen definiert:

> Eine Person mit dem Eintrag „divers“ hat ein Geschlecht, dass sie vom männlichen oder weiblichen unterscheidet.

Personen, die keine Angabe zu ihrem Geschlecht machen (können auch nicht-binäre Menschen sein), fühlen sich meist keinem Geschlecht zugehörig oder möchten mit keinem Geschlecht in Verbindung gebracht werden. Daher die geschlechtsneutralere Anrede "Person".

Natürlich sind die Definitionen schwammig und jeder definiert "divers" anders. Man könnte auch die Anrede "Person" sowohl bei "divers" als auch bei "keine Angabe" nehmen.

Comment: Ich habe auch schon häufig in Briefen und E-Mails "Hallo Vorname Nachname" gelesen. Das finde ich eigentlich auch elegant, da du keine Fallunterscheidungen hinsichtlich des Geschlechts treffen musst. Das einzige was ich daran etwas schade finde ist, dass "Hallo" von manchen vielleicht als nicht ganz so freundlich interpretiert wird wie "Sehr geehrte(r) ...".